# Overflow using Fixed-Point Chebyshev Method

Tags: arm, fixed-point, trigonometry, cortex-m

I have an algorithm in an embedded system that needs to calculate sin(theta), sin(2*theta), sin(3*theta), etc) with Q15 fixed-point arithmetic.  sin(theta) and cos(theta) are generated using a LUT/interpolation combo, but I'm using the Chebyshev method to calculate the higher order Sines, which looks like this (pseudo-code):

```
 sinN1 = Comes from Q15 LUT/interp algorithm
 cosN1 = Comes from Q15 LUT/interp algorithm

 sinN2 = (cosN1*sinN1)>>14;
 sinN3 = (cosN1*sinN2)>>14 - sinN1;
 sinN4 = (cosN1*sinN3)>>14 - sinN2;
 ....
```

The problem is that under certain conditions, this method yields a result which can overflow a Q15 variable.  For example, lets consider when theta =2.61697:

```
 sinN1 (Q15) = int(2**15*sin(2.61697)) = 16413
 cosN1 (Q15) = int(2**15*cos(2.61697)) = -28361
 sinN2 = (-28361*16413)>>14 = -28412            # OK
 sinN3 = (-28361*-28412)>>14 - 16413 = 32768    # OVERFLOW BY 1
 ..
```

I never seem to overflow by more than an LSB or two.  It seems to be an artifcat of compounding quantization.  I'm using an ARM Cortex M4 processor, so I can add saturation logic with relatively few instructions, but I'm doing a lot of real-time streaming DSP with very low latency requirements so I  need to save as much CPU as I can so I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to handle this issue.

Comment: You could probably use unsigned arithmetic as the +/- will be determined by a check on the quadrants.  There may be other ways to estimate the function and/or tweak the co-efficients.  You didn't give the actual function that is being estimated?

Answer (score 0):

The mathematician in me wants to suggest keeping an estimate of the accumulated error and correcting for it in a sigma-delta fashion as elegant, but the pragmatic programmer in me says that's insanely impractical.

The [`SSAT`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BABBGFBI.html) instruction will saturate your result to any position you want, costs a single cycle, and should be easily available via the `__ssat` intrinsic on any non-rubbish compiler. Since you will inevitably accumulate errors with any non-integer arithmetic, I'm not sure there's really anything better than just doing the calculation and spending one extra cycle making sure it's in range.

---

What I can't quite work out is if you could get it entirely for free by dabbling in a bit of (inline) assembly to get at the optional shift in `ssat` that the intrinsic doesn't expose, on the basis that the multiplication/FP correction step is the biggest source of error; something like (pseudo-assembly):

```
mul  tmp, cosN1, sinN2
ssat tmp, #16, tmp, asr #14
sub  sinN3, tmp, sinN1
```

Which you can only safely get away with if you can guarantee to never end up with something like sinN3 = 0 - (-32768). [`QSUB16`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/CHDBHGFC.html) is tempting to replace the `SUB`, but being a parallel operation would do weird stuff with the top halfword of sign bits, and as soon as you add a mask or halfword-packing instruction to correct for that you've lost the "for free" game.